# ConfigParser Error when running python script from RoR app's controller

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to trigger a python script from a controller.

I have defined the follwing function in the controller:

```
 private
     def update_product_count(skus, qty)
       system "python2 /home/nish/stuff/repos/Untitled/voylla_staging_changes/app/models/ReviseItem.py
 skus qty > output"
     end
```

Calling this function in another method of the same controller:

```
def show
//some code
update_product_count(@skus, @qty)
end
```

When I run the script manually, from my console, it runs fine. But i get this error when run from the controller:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nish/stuff/repos/Untitled/voylla_staging_changes/app/models/ReviseItem.py", line 24, in <module>
    devID = config.get("Keys", "Developer")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Keys'
```

Comment: the statment system "python2 /home/nish/stuff/repos/Untitled/voylla_staging_changes/app/models/ReviseItem.py
 skus qty > output" shoule be rewrite as system "python2 /home/nish/stuff/repos/Untitled/voylla_staging_changes/app/models/ReviseItem.py
 #{skus} #{qty} > output". otherwise you will output the string instead of the actual passed in value.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you are opening the config file using a relative path, and the controller has a different current directory to your console.

You should either use an absolute path to the config file, or have the script work out the directory it is executing in, and prepend that to the file name.